# How to override action method in .NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to rewrite an action that exists in one control in override control that inherits from the previous one. Is this possible? The desired code sample.

Base controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public virtual IActionResult test()
   {
     ....
   }
}
```

`SampleController`:

```
public class SampleController : BaseController
{
   public override IActionResult test()
   {
      // ....
      return base.test();
   }
}
```

Is this possible override the action method?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible - the base method is defined as `virtual`, so it can be overridden in a descendent class using `override` (as you do). Only thing that seems a bit odd: the *base* method has a `[HttpPost]` annotation - but the overridden method does not ..... maybe you just need to add the `[HttpPost]` to the overridden method and then call it with a `POST` request

Answer (score 1):

That sound possible

```cs
public class foo
{
    public virtual void bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mother");
    }
}

public class foofoo : foo
{
    public override void bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child");
        base.bar();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var hi = new foofoo();
       hi.bar();
       //return *Child* then *Mother*
    }
}
```

But as @marc_s explain it, it's odd to not use [HttpPost] on the override.
You can make the two "action" reachable as two end point : one with `[HttpPost(api/test/mother)]` and the second with `[HttpPost(api/test/mother/child)]`